# horizontal scroll bar does not appear

Tags: html, css

Horizontal scroll bar not appearing on Chrome of *Mac Version 79.0.3945.130*

Here is the CSS:

```
position: relative;
background-color: #f4f4f4;
padding: 25px 30px;
margin: 0 0 20px;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 1.5;
overflow-x: auto;
```

Comment: set width and see like `width: 120%`

Comment: @skdroid It works for the whole page. But I mean it's not working on the particular div

Comment: do you have width to that specific div?

Comment: @KalleshwarKalshetty no

Comment: Try with putting some width for that div.

Answer (score 0):

use `overflow-x: scroll;` along with a width or min-width it should work